# How to Bind an input array to the attributes of an object

Tags: arrays, vb.net, oop

Here is my problem :

I have a class **Temp** that has 3 attributes.

```
public class Temp 
    public property attribute1 as string
    public property attribute2 as string
    public property attribute3 as string
end Class
```

I would like to pass an array of strings to the constructor of the class and bind each element from the array to one attribute in order

So here is my code (This assumes that the length of the input array d matches the number of attributes in the class Temp )

```
            'd is the input array of Strings
            Dim temp As New Temp
            Dim propertyinfo() = temp.GetType().GetProperties()
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each proper In propertyinfo
                proper.SetValue(temp, d(i))    
                i = i + 1
            Next
```

When the attributes of the class Temp are all string, this works fine. However, if the type is not string (such Date type), a casting exception happens even though the input element of the array is a valid Date but in a string format.

My question is there anyway to cast automatically each element of d to the type of the attributes when I do this operation

```
                proper.SetValue(temp, d(i))
```

Thank you

Comment: what is wrong with `attribute1 = d(0)`, *especially* from the ctor?

Comment: I have a class with more than 250 attributes. I do not wanna initialize the attributes one by one but through a loop

Comment: From MSDN: `The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order` so unless the properties are really `foo1`, `foo2` and it doesnt matter what is assigned to each, a loop wont help.  And if it *doesnt* matter, then convert the property to a `List(of String)` and save the array to it (addrange or in the list ctor).